# Google Calendar API fails after a few days after running fine

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I run freebusy queries on Google calendar accounts with a stored refresh_token.

Each grant is performed via the standard API grant process (the app is verified and in production), and the user provided the necessary consent for the freebusy scope.

A daily cron job that performs this freebusy query to see when the API fails worked for multiple days, then it suddenly fails with "invalid grant". Here is the relevant code snippet that runs as a firebase function

```
try {       
    console.debug('Setting Oauth credentials with refresh token ' + refreshToken);
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        refresh_token: refreshToken // <----- stored in our database
    });
    console.debug('Credentials are now: ' + JSON.stringify(oauth2Client));
    google.options({
        auth: oauth2Client
      });
    var tokens = await oauth2Client.getAccessToken(); // <--- obtaining access token
    console.debug('outside tokens: ' + JSON.stringify(tokens));
    var calendar = google.calendar('v3', oauth2Client);
    freeBusy = await calendar.freebusy.query(
        freeBusyBody
    );
} catch (error) {
    console.error('native calendar freeBusy API' + error );
    throw new Error( error );
}
```

Comment: When the access token refreshes, both the refresh token and new access token get replaced. Are you storing the new tokens?

Comment: That may be the case some times. Do you know when that happen? Otherwise I need to check if the refresh token changed. The code runs fine multiple times over the span of multiple days. Here are the refresh token values from the log after each call in the code above: 
from db
1//04t7lv...fmQ
after oauth2client.setCredentials
1//04t7lv...LfmQ
after  oauth2Client.getAccessToken
"res": {
 "data" = "refresh_token=1%2F%2F04t7lv...fmQ..."
} 
data: {
 "refresh_token": "1//04t7lv ...fmQ"
}

Comment: Every time the access token expires, you will get new tokens. I know in google's case when that is, but if you don't have anything in your code that handles refresh token changes, then that's likely the culprit.

Comment: Not quite, but you pointed me on the right track after sifting through before/after logs I found the event when the token switched. While the access token in Google expires after an hour, the refresh token lasts for several days, but not forever.